# Is there a way to compile protobuf and all its plugins together?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf-python

Right now I need to compile my protobuf and all the plugins(imported) separately.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you give us more detail?

Comment: Protobuf is a language created by google to define structured data. You compile protobuf into source code in different languages(i'm using python) which you can then use to serialize and deserialize data. Part of the language syntax are imports which is exectly what it sounds, importing other files or plugins(I am using nanopb as a plugin). When compiling the protobuf i created it only compiles my own file and not the plugin. I am wandering if there is a way to compile a file and all its imports together instead of doing them one by one